# How to calculate age from DOB if month is invalid?

Tags: javascript, c#, regex, typescript, datetime

I have a date field which accepts if the *month* is *unknown*. And I calculate the `age` from the date entered and the current date and time.

```js
var birthDate = new Date("12 UNK 1995");
var now = new Date();
var age = now.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();

document.write("Your Age is: " + age);
```

If the run this is throwing me **`NaN`** error. I think it is because of that invalid date format.

Is there any way that I can calculate the `age` even if the *month* is *unknown* based on the *year* only in any kind of date formate?

Comment: What is the source of the date string? Will need to parse it if it isn't a valid format. Of course accuracy gets lost when month is unknown

Comment: Yea if the parse it is saying that it is in Invalid format.

Comment: I mean you need to break that string down into it's parts and use only the valid parts. No real need to use `new Date`

Comment: Are you asking how to parse `Strings` of the pattern `"DD UNK YYYY"`, or are you really asking for *"any kind of date format"*? The former we can answer, the latter is impossible.

Comment: @MaxVollmer i am qsking  how to parse of the pattern " DD UNK YYYY"

Answer (score 3):

If the month is unknown then the normal way programmatically to set it to the middle of the year – to July. I know this problem in India – some people do not know their birth date sometimes.

For example like follows:

```js
var month = "UNK"; // TODO: here is your code to get the month name from field

month = month == "UNK" ? "JUL" : month;

var birthDate = new Date("12 " + month + " 1995");
var now = new Date();
var age = now.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();

document.write("Your Age is: " + age);
```

*But note that your calculation is not really correct because you do not calculate with full date (day, month, year, hour, minutes).*

**My suggestion**

But I would like to suggest to use a new HTML5 input field type **[`date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date)** (see this link) which looks like follows (go with mouse pointer over this field):

```html
<input name="birthdate" type="date" required>
```

And all users have to put in this date on their's own accountability. In this case they have to choose one date and you will do not have the accountability for this.

Answer (score 1):

You have the year already in a string so extract it from the string and then substract from year now.

Comment: And you can do that with a regex search: `var year = Number('12 UNK 1995'.match(/\d{4}/g)[0]);`

Comment: What is the guarantee that the year will be in the last 4 characters?

Comment: That will pick up the first instance of a group of 4 succeeding digits at any position in a string. Try it with a few different samples.

Comment: Please mark my answer as the answer what helped you.

Comment: @HariKrishna, but this is wrong way to calculate the age only with year. For example: some user is born on 15 December 1995 and we have  today 09. September 2018. With your wrong calculation in this case this user would be already **23 years old**, but this is wrong! This user is **22 years old only today**. Your calculation is not really correct because you do not calculate with full date (day, month, year, hour, minutes).

Comment: @Bharata, the problem HariKrishna is having it that the month is unknown. In this case, you cannot go any other direction than calculate with the year only

Comment: @user1803096 May I know why you are using `[0]` at the end. I didn't understand that.

Comment: @Aldert, if the month is unknown then the normal way programmatically to set it to the middle of the year – to July.

Comment: @Bharata I have already written other validation to encounter that type of scenario. I am only facing the issue if the month is Unknown

Comment: @Hari Krishna, it is the first match (that is how regex works).

Comment: @Bharata, if we would talk about averages and do reporting on it, I would agree that would be the right thing to do. In this case I do not see it relevant.